# mongodb replica set backup using rsync

Tags: rsync, mongodb

I have configured *mongodb* replica set (I have 3 db instances -Redhat) and I would like to take a backup of db file ( dbPath: */var/lib/mongo*) using `rsync`, 10 or 12 times per day.

1. So, do I need to stop the `mongod` process before start `rsync`?

   - select one of the server of replica set and stop the mongod process
   - take the backup (using rsync)
   - start the mongod process
2. or else, can I start `rsync` (dbPath: */var/lib/mongo*) without stopping the `mongod` process.
3. what is the recommended backup method other than LVM backup and `mongodump`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, do I need to stop the `mongod` process before start `rsync`?

To take a file copy backup with `rsync` or `cp` you need to quiesce writes by stopping the `mongod` service or issuing the [`db.fsyncLock()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/) command in the `mongo` shell or via a driver.  Since the secondary you are backing up from will be intermittently available with this approach, it would be best to make it [hidden](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/) to avoid drivers trying to read from this member when it is down or fsyncLock'd.

I would make sure you test several full backup and restore cycles. In particular, be wary of `rsync` options that might invalidate backups (for example: `--ignore-existing`, `--size-only`, `--partial`).

Note: if you are using the `fsyncLock()` approach there is a [`db.fsyncUnLock()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.fsyncUnlock/) command to restore normal operation after your backup completes. Another caveat: the WiredTiger storage engine only supports `fsyncLock` in MongoDB 3.2 or newer.

> can I start `rsync` (dbPath: */var/lib/mongo*) without stopping the `mongod` process.

No. This will result in an inconsistent backup.

> what is the recommended backup method other than LVM backup and `mongodump`?

Supported backup approaches are described in the documentation: [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/).

There are less disruptive (and more continuous) backup approaches such as using an agent-based backup service (for example, MongoDB Cloud Manager).

If you want to backup by copying underlying data files, filesystem snapshots (LVM/EBS/...) are generally less disruptive and more recommendable than pausing all writes to a `mongod`. Filesystem snapshots against a running `mongod` do have some requirements if you want to capture a consistent backup: all data must be on the same volume, journaling must be enabled, and the filesystem must support point-in-time snapshots. For full details, check out the official documentation and backup tutorials.